# Javascript: выделение части пути с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, поиск

Стоит задача:

Есть путь к файлу в следующих видах:

`/path1/path2/path3/prefix1_filename.ext`

`/path1/path2/filename.ext`

`prefix2_filename.ext`

Необходимо

1) выделить `filename`

2) определить, какой префикс перед `filename` стоит и стоит ли вообще

**Подскажите как это лучше сделать через регулярные выражения (вроде как всё в 1 строчку можно сделать)**

```
let res = /regexp/i.exec(path);
```

список префиксов имеется `thumb`, `mini`, `big` и т.п.

Т.е. если будет такой путь:

`/path1/path2/path3/prefixA_filename.ext`

и такого `prefixA` в списке префиксов нет, то имя должно выделиться не `filename`, а `prefixA_filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нахимичил следующий regexp:

`/(.*)(([/](thumb|mini|big)[_])|[/])([^/.]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$/`

Пример в работе:

```js
const urls = [
  "/path1/path2/path3/prefix1_filename.ext",
  "/path1/path2/new_filename.ext",
  "/path1/path2/path3/thumb_filename.ext",
  "/mini_filename.ext",
  "/path1/path2/big_filename.ext",
  "/path1/path2/path3/filename.ext",
  "/path1/path2/path3/new_new_filename.ext",
];

urls.forEach(url => {
  const res = url.match(/(.*)(([/](thumb|mini|big)[_])|[/])([^/.]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$/);
  const filename = res[5];
  const prefix = res[4] || 'нет';
  $("#results").append('url: '+url+'<br>');
  $("#results").append('prefix: '+prefix+', file: '+filename);
  $("#results").append('<br><br>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">

</div>
```

Comment: вроде сработало, но в индексации можно быть уверенным? Она не съедет, если путь будет разной степени глубины?

Comment: индексация в любом случае будет одинаковая. Если мы правильно друг-друга поняли.